# Overload =operator, can't get it to work

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the =operator on line 9 in the code below:

```
void searchContact(vector<Person> &people){
    string searchTerm;
    vector<Person>::iterator it;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter search term: ";
    getline(cin, searchTerm);

    it = find(people.begin(), people.end(), searchTerm);

    if (it != people.end()){
        cout << "Element found in: " << *it << '\n';
    }else{
        cout << "Element not found\n";
    }
}
```

My approach is this:

```
  int data;

  Person& operator=(Person& a) { return a; }
  Person& operator=(int a) {
    data = a;
    return *this;
  }
```

I am getting this error:

```
class.cpp:129:30: error: ‘Person& operator=(Person&)’ must be a nonstatic member function
   Person& operator=(Person& a) { return a; }
                              ^
class.cpp:130:26: error: ‘Person& operator=(int)’ must be a nonstatic member function
   Person& operator=(int a) {
```

What is wrong with my approach, or am i doing it all wrong from the beginning?

Comment: Are you sure you want to create an *assignment* operator? And not a comparison-for-equal `==` operator?

Comment: As for the errors you get, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Lastly, I recommend you read [this reference of canonical implementations of overloaded operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations), because your copy-assignment operator is wrong (it doesn't copy anything for starters).

Comment: As the error is telling you, the operator needs to a member function of the class you're assigning to. It doesn't look like thats the case?

Comment: Another thing to note is that a `std::string` is being passed to `std::find()`.  In order for that to work with a `std::vector<Person>`, you need an `operator==` overload that takes a `std::string` as input instead of a `Person`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are overloading the wrong operator.  `std::find()` uses `operator==` (comparison) instead of `operator=` (assignment).  And, given that you are passing a `std::string` to `std::find()`, you need an `operator==` that takes a `std::string` as input, not a `Person`.

Second, you are trying to implement the operators as unary operators, which means they MUST be non-static members of your `Person` class.  The compiler is complaining that they are not.

Third, if `std::find()` finds a match, you are passing `*it` to `std::cout`, so you need an overloaded `operator<<` that takes a `Person` for output.

Try something like this:

```
class Person
{
public:
    ...

    bool operator==(const string &rhs) const
    {
        // compare members of *this to rhs as needed...
        return ...; // true or false
    }

    /* alternatively:
    friend bool operator==(const Person &lhs, const string &rhs)
    {
        // compare members of lhs to rhs as needed...
        return ...; // true or false
    }
    */

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Person &p)
    {
        // output p to out as needed...
        return out;
    }

    ...
};
```

Then your search code will work:

```
void searchContact(vector<Person> &people)
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter search term: ";

    string searchTerm;
    getline(cin, searchTerm);

    vector<Person>::iterator it = find(people.begin(), people.end(), searchTerm);    

    if (it != people.end()) {
        cout << "Element found in: " << *it << '\n';
    } else {
        cout << "Element not found\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Person{

private:
     int data;

public:
    Person(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
    }

    int getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    friend bool operator==( const Person &lhs, const int rhs);
};
bool operator== ( const Person &lhs, const int rhs )
{
    return lhs.data == rhs;
}

void searchContact(std::vector<Person> &people){
    int searchTerm = 1;
    vector<Person>::iterator it;

    it = find(people.begin(), people.end(), searchTerm);

    if (it != people.end()){
        cout << "Element found in: " << it->getData() << '\n';
    }else{
        cout << "Element not found\n";
    }
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<Person> list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::vector<Person> list2 = {1, 2, 3, 5};
    std::vector<Person> list3 = {1, 3, 7, 6, 9, 5, 2, 4};

    searchContact(list1);
    searchContact(list2);
    searchContact(list3);
}
```

i don't know what do you want. please show your full code and tell what do you want.

if you want to find element in vector, you can write like this(not string. if ou want to find string, just change int to string and get data with cin or etc)

Comment: `(*it).getData()` can also be written as `it->getData()`